Is deduction an integral part of induction (logic)?
Definitions:
Deduction: The conclusion necessarily follows with 100% certainty from the premises. Impossible for the conclusion to be false and the premises true (valid)
Induction: The conclusion doesn't follow necessarily with 100% certainy from the premises. Possible that the premises are true and the conclusion false (invalid).
Consider the inductive argument below:

90% of Americans are good = A
John is an American = J
Ergo,
There's 90% chance that John is good = G

The truth of A and  J doesn't guarantee although it does increase the probability that John is probably good, hence inductive.
As far as I can tell the argument (is known as a statistical argument) also has the following form:

If (A & J) then G
A & J
Ergo,
G

This is a deductive argument form known as modus ponens. If A and J then, by the mathematics of probability it is necessary that G. This as you can see is a deductive argument.
So my question is, do all inductive arguments come in this form, as always nested within or dependent on a deductive argument?

No, inductive inference is a generalization of deductive one that tracks degree of support, see inductive logic. Your argument is not even that, it is a deductive syllogism with statistical premise and conclusion.

Si, that's a good point. but doesn't the conclusion G follows necessarily from the premises A and J (as per mathematical probability). Are you saying mathematical probability is wrong in some way?

It follows necessarily by modus ponens, not by probability. That probability is mentioned in the claims is moot as far as inferring is concerned here, it is not used to make the inference. You do not change the logical form of "Men are mortal, Socrates is a man, Socrates is mortal" by replacing "mortal" with "has 10% chance of developing diabetes". It remains purely deductive.

@Conifold, but the inductive inference made, John is probably good depends on the deductive inference based on mathematical probability. Say the deductive, mathematical probability-based argument is bad in some way. Automatically, we lose the inductive justification for John is probably good, no?

I do not see a probability-based argument in your example. "All men in a large sample are good, so all men are probably good" is a probability-based (inductive) argument, "all men are probably good, John is a man, so John is probably good" is not, despite the "probably" in it. I do not know what "deductive inference based on mathematical probability" refers to. Do you simply mean deductive arguments with inductively supported premises? That two types of arguments can be combined does not make one "integral part" of the other, and inferring as such is not "based" on how premises are supported.

Those are not the definitions of deduction and induction.

The inference in your example might better be called probabilistic-deductive. You can deduce one probability from another. Inductive logic, or confirmation theory as it is also called, is concerned with accounting for how the premises of an argument can support a conclusion without entailing it.

@Bumble, that's sound judgment. Gracias. I'm mainly concerned about grounding. What justifies induction? Looks like, from the example in the OP, at least in the case of statistical inductive arguments, it's deduction.

Inductive inference is not really deductive. Or at least it cannot be reduced to rules in the way deduction can. I said something about this in my answer to this question.

@Bumble, I'm not saying induction = deduction. I was inquiring into the justifications for induction. At least for this particular example of induction (statistical argument), that seems to be deduction. The conclusion is probabilistic (John is probably good), but necessarily John is probably good, no?

The example would need tidying up. If you conduct an experiment in which you select an American at random with a uniform distribution then the person selected has a 90% probability of being good in the absence of any other information. But the example is highly artificial. You rarely know only one thing about an experiment. As soon as you know more than one, then you run into the reference class problem.
